# Is it manageable for postgresql to manage a table with 1.5 billion rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table was simply with an id, string within 400 charaters, and a length item to record the length of its string. The problem was, when I do a query, e.g `select * from table where length = whatever a number` It never reacts. (or always caltulates... ) I was wondering, if it was due to the large dataset? Should I somehow split the table into several? But I noticed that, when executing query like above, there are three threads about postgresql with only 2 MB RAM occupation each and 4-5 MB transmission rate. Was it normal? 
[image]

Environment: 12GB RAM, Postgresql 12 on Win10.

Comment: Do you have an index on that column?

Comment: Postgres seems to only use 5% CPU - what is eating the other 55% CPU on your system? Which Postgres version is that?

Comment: This might be better asked on the sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com, as it is not really a programming problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque didn't know the page, thanks a lot!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was opening the snipping tool while doing the shot， maybe taht's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly normal.

Your query is performing a parallel [sequential scan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) with two additional worker processes. Reading a large table from disk neither requires much RAM nor much CPU. You are probably [I/O bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound).

Two remarks:

- Depending on the number of result rows, an index on the column or expression in the `WHERE` clause can speed up processing considerably.
- Unless you really need it for speed, storing the length of the string in an extra column is bad practice. You can calculate that from the string itself.

  Storing such redundant data not only wastes a little space, it opens the door to inconsistencies (unless you have a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)).

All this is not PostgreSQL specific, it will be the same with any database.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes,  did really need the length because the programm will first just need to read the length without knowing the string. And was that because of the large dataset that when i executing query it did not come out with any result?

Comment: You didn't specify whether the query never finished or whether it returned no results. In the first case you didn't wait long enough, in the second case there was no row that satisfied the condition.